# An ideal of $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^2)$ that isn't free.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, free-modules

I'm currently studying for an exam and redoing my old Homework. I came across this task and don't really understand the solution to it anymore. Task:

> Let $R:=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$. Find a strict $R$-submodule (not equal to the $0$-module) $I$ so that $I$ is not a free module.

I already know a solution to that: $(X+(X^2))$. However I don't really understand the approach to this task and have a few general questions:

I) What exactly are the ideals of $R$? How do they look like?

II) What exactly is $(X+(X^2))$? Is that equal to $R(X+(X^2))$?

III) How do I come up with this solution? I already have a proof that has been discussed in my course weeks ago, but I just don't understand it anymore. Perhaps someone has an idea on how to solve this task. Thank you in advance for answers!

Comment: Notation rant: Some people insist on writing the elements of $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2)$ as $f + (X^2)$, with $f\in \Bbb Q[X]$. I think that gets messy. Some people are, in my opinion, more reasonable and write $\bar f$ or $[f]$ instead. It has the bonus of a single element being a single symbol, rather than 3. In the case of looking at ideals, I definitely find $(\bar f)$ easier to read than $(f + (X^2))$. (Personally, I prefer to just write $f$, and use the same notation for elements of $\Bbb Q[X]$ as for elements of $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2)$. But that's best to avoid until you're very comfortable with this.)

Comment: I've only really seen the first notation you mentioned, that's the one im familiar with. However I didn't take many algebra courses thus far and struggling with them quite hard. Can you tell me what exactly (f+(X^2)) means? Isn't that what I stated in my post above? Thank you!

Comment: You're right about what it means, yes. All possible multiples of $X+(X^2)$

Comment: If $k$ is a field, then a $k[x]$ module is the same thing as a $k$-vector space $V$, and a linear operator $T: V \to V$ giving the action of $x$. A $k[x]$-submodules of $V$ will be any subspace invariant under $T$. Can you take it from here? $k[x]/(x^2)$ is two dimensional, so it should be easy to pick a basis and write out $T$ as a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I) In general, let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $I$ and ideal in $R$. Then we have a bijective correspondence

$$ \{J \subseteq R ~ \text{an ideal} ~: I \subseteq J\} \rightarrow \{ A  \subseteq R/I~ \text{an ideal}\} \\
J \mapsto \pi(J) $$

In particular, let $a \in J$, then $a + I \in J/I$ is the corresponding element in $R$.

II) $(X + (X^2))_R$ is the ideal generated in $R$ by the element $X + (X^2)=:b$ i.e. the smallest ideal containing $(X + (X^2))_R$. Since $b$ is a single element, $(b)_R$ is principal and thus $(b)_R = Rb = \{rb \vert r \in R\}$.

III) Finding an proper submodule of $R$ which is not free now amounts to finding an ideal $J \subseteq R$ containing $(X^2)$ s.t. $\pi(J)$ is not free. The only proper ideal in $R$ which contains $(X^2)$ is $(X)$. Hence if there exists an answer to the question it has to be $\pi((X))$. Since $(X)$ is a principal ideal the only possible generator of $(X + (X^2))$ is $b$. However, while $b$ does span the entire module, it is not linearly independent, since $b \cdot b = 0$. Hence there does not exist a basis for $(X + (X^2))$ and thus it is not free.

Comment: Alright, so the first thing you mentioned means that A is an Ideal of R/I exactly when A is an Ideal of R that contains I? Why does one then write (X+(X^2)) instead of (X), shouldnt that be the same thing? Or did I not understand that correctly and A is an ideal of R/I exactly when A=J+I where J is an Ideal of R that contains I? Im slightly confused by this. If I understand you correctly your second answer is the same as what I stated in my post isn't it? The rest should be very clear, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In the first part I write that $\pi(J)$ i.e. $J/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$ exactly when $J$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $I$. In your example this means that $\pi((X))$ is an ideal in $R$ since $(X)$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ containing $(X^2)$. $(X + (X^2))$ denotes the ideal generated in $R$ by the element $X + (X^2)$. The element $X$ is not in $R$, but in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ so $(X)$ is not an ideal in $R$.

Comment: I've tried it this way: I is an ideal of R exactly when there exists an Ideal J of Q[X] that contains (X^2) with pi (J)=I. Since Q[X] is a principal ideal domain it follows that J=(X). Therefore I=pi (J) = (X)+(X^2). This should be equal to (X+(X^2)) shouldn't it? If it is, I know that X+(X^2) isn't linearly independent, due to what you already stated. However I need to make sure that it's the only span of the ideal don't I? Another generator could theoretically be able to be linearly independent couldn't it? Thank you!

Comment: $I = \pi(J)$ but this is not equal to $(X) + (X^2)$. The notation $(X) + (X^2)$ means the sum of the ideal i.e. all the elements of the form $aX + bX^2$ and is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. What you want is $(X + (X^2))$, where $X + (X^2)$ is the coset of $X$ in the ring $R$ i.e. the image of $X$ under the projection $\pi: \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[x]/(X^2)$.

Comment: Yes, $X+(X^2)$ is only one possible generator. However, since $(X+(X^2))$ is principal, any other generator is associated to $X+(X^2)$, meaning it is a unit multiple of $X + (X^2)$. This will lead to the same result. i.e. that the generator is nilpotent

Comment: I think I see my first error: pi((X))= (pi(X)) isn't it? I think this is where I went wrong. However, how do you know it's a unit multiple? This shouldn't make any difference though, since all other generators look like q*(X+(X^2)) (not meaning the span here) where q is an element of Q[X]/(X^2). Multiplying this by X+(X^2) should still give 0. Therefore it is solved isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. It’s by definition a unit multiple, because they are associated if they generate the same principal ideal. But as you said, you don’t need to use that it is a unit

Comment: Do you know a different explanation for why pi(X)=(X+(X^2))? And btw, thanks a lot for your help! I understood this problem now.

Comment: No, $\pi(X)$ i.e. the image of the element $X$ under the map $\pi$ is not equal to $(X + (X^2))$ which is the ideal generated by the element $X + (X^2)$. However, $\pi(X) = X + (X^2)$, which is by definition of the projection $\pi: \mathbb{Q}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$. Also we have $\pi((X)_{\mathbb{Q}[x]}) = (\pi(X))_R = (X + (X^2))_R$ i.e. where $\pi((X))$ is the image of the ideal $(X)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. (here the subscript after the paranthesis indicates in which ring the ideal is). The last equality is due to the definition of each ideal. Also, you're very welcome.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I seem to have forgotten the paranthesis. What I meant was pi((X))=(X+(X^2)). It should be correct then.

Comment: Yes, it is. Write up a proof though.

Comment: I basically did write a proof above didn't I? There were only 2 steps missing in the end, which I now would be able to add due to your help. If you want to I can try to write a complete proof though.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you understood why this is true. Carry on

Comment: Yes, I understand it perfectly well now! Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Every element of $R$ can be written in the form $a + b X$, with $a, b \in \mathbb Q$. (Strictly speaking, the class of $a+bX$ in the quotient $\mathbb Q[X] / (X^2)$.)

So, suppose now that $I$ is a proper nonzero ideal that contains $a+bX$.

Because $I$ is proper, $a+bX$ must not be invertible in $R$. Note that $X$ is nilpotent, and recall that a nilpotent element plus a unit is again a unit. What does this tell about $a, b$? How many nonzero proper ideals does $R$ have?

You should find that $(X)$ is the only nonzero proper ideal of $R$. Is it free? It must not be, because otherwise the question has no answer. Can you show that a single element of $(X)$ is not linearly independent?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since I haven't taken many algebra courses yet, I'm struggling with some of the things you said. Why is it possible to write every element that way? I've also never heard of nilpotent in this context (not a native english speaker, maybe because of that), does it have the same meaning as in the context of a matrix?

Comment: For $a+bX$: equivalently, what I'm saying is that every element of $\mathbb Q[X]$ is of the form $a+bX + P \cdot X^2$ for some $P \in R[X]$. A nilpotent element of a ring is an $a$ for which there exists $n$ with $a^n = 0$. A special case is indeed a nilpotent matrix, as an element of the matrix ring. You can google "sum of nilpotents is nilpotent" or "nilpotent plus unit is invertible" and try to understand the proof (or try prove it yourself!).